# Gmail is cut off and show HTML in content

Tags: html, css, user-interface, templates, gmail

I have a problem with Gmail is cut off when the size exceeds 102KB. Email cut off and then auto add text cut of from HTML code. How can I remove this text and have a beautiful email? Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKkdI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD5xU.png)

Comment: What's the HTML you're trying to put in the email?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to put HTML in the email, I want to remove them. HTML code auto is cut off and add to my email.